# Element removing while collection iterating

Tags: java, collections

I'm wondering what is really going on behind the scene when I'm executing the following peace of code:

```
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    fillTheList(); // Filling a list with 10 objects
    int count = 0;
    for (Object o : list) {
        count++;
        if (count == 5) {
            list.remove(count);
        }
        o.toString();
     }
```

Once element is removed I'm getting `ConcurrentModificationException` exception.

I don't understand why after one of elements removing it is impossible just to take the next one available in the collection and proceed with a cycle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

get an `Iterator` instead of using the iterator in a `for` loop:

```
int count = 0;

for(final Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    final Object o = iterator.next();

    if (++count == 5) {
        iterator.remove();
    }

    o.toString();
}
```

*edit*: the reason why you get `ConcurrentModificationException` is because the `for` loop is using a different `Iterator` which was created before your modification will being made with `list.remove()` and that `Iterator` has a state inside.

Comment: That's an idea, but I really want to know the mechanism why it is impossible after one element removal just to take the next Object from a queue and proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're not allowed to refer to the collection (`list` in this case) inside the foreach loop.

Try this instead:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
fillTheList(); // Filling a list with 10 objects
int count = 0;
ListIterator<Object> it = list.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object o = it.next();
    count++;
    if (count == 5) {
        it.remove();
    }
    o.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is usually a better way to do this rather than use iterator.remove(). e.g. in your case, the loop is the same as

```
if(list.size()> 5) list.remove(5);
```

If you do need to use iterator.remove() you can still use a for loop.

```
for(Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    final Object o = iterator.next();

    if (++count == 5)
       iterator.remove();

    o.toString();
}
```